# drop down display empty rows although i get data filled on RefreshDropDownList function?

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, c#-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I work on `blazor on .net core 7` . i face issue when display drop down server type

issue is drop down server type display empty although I get data on function `RefreshDropDownList();` .

I work on blazor page server names data and inside this page there are drop down servertype

so server type drop down exist on another page `ServersNames`

server type drop down display empty although function RefreshDropDownList() return 4 items data .
so what is issue and How to solve it ? .

controller action fill drop down is

```
  [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            return Ok(_IserverTypeService.GetAll());
            
        }
```

I test action `GetAll` on controller `service type` and it return data without any issue

on blazor ui :

```
<h1>Server Name</h1>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-2 float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" @onclick="AddClick">
    Add ServerNames

</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                    @ModalTitle
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
                    <div class="p-2 w-100 bd-highlight">
                       
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="example-text-input" class="col-3 col-form-label">Server Type</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
          @*          <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="server_Type" />*@
                                <select class="form-select" @bind="server_Type">
                                    @foreach (var servertype in ServerType)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@servertype.serverTypeId">
                                            @servertype.serverType
                                        </option>
                                    }

                    </select>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                     
                    </div>
                   
                  
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>



@code
{
    public class ServerNamesClass
    {
        public string server_Type { get; set; }
    }
    public class ServerTypesClass
    {
        public int serverTypeId { get; set; }
        public string serverType { get; set; }
    }
   
    private IEnumerable<ServerTypesClass> ServerType = Array.Empty<ServerTypesClass>();

    

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await   RefreshDropDownList();
    }

   
    private async Task RefreshDropDownList()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, config["API_URL"] + "ServerTypes");
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        using var responsestream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        ServerType = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<ServerTypesClass>>(responsestream);
        ServerType = Array.Empty<ServerTypesClass>();


    }
   

    private async void AddClick()
    {
        await RefreshDropDownList();
   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `RefreshDropDownList()` you overwrite your ServerType IEnumerable with an empty list: `ServerType = Array.Empty<ServerTypesClass>();`. This means that your deserialized data will always be overwritten with an empty list.